# do we need to use a mutex lock when accessing Grails global variables?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm wondering 
In grails's global variables - do we need to add mutex lock when access them ?
Example

- Static variable in XXXService Class
- Grails Application Context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm wondering In grails's global variables - do we need to add mutex
>   lock when access them ?

The JVM doesn't really have global variables.  The closest thing to them are public static variables, which isn't really the same thing.

Whether or not you have to add a mutex depends on what you want to do with the variables.  In general, the answer is "no", but that is in part because in general you wouldn't want to have mutable public static variables.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to synchronize these objects if they need to be thread safe. Most things in the Grails Application Context do not need to be (such as just getting a singleton service).

So the answer to your question is not very clear-cut. Do it when you feel it is necessary to make sure that previous process has finished with the variable you care about.

Comment: "You only need to synchronize these objects if they need to be thread safe.  Most things in the Grails Application Context do not need to be (such as just getting a singleton service)." - It is definitely not true that most things in the app context don't need to be thread safe.  They specifically do need to be thread safe, especially singleton services.  You definitely want singleton services to be thread safe.  They will be accessed by multiple threads concurrently.

Comment: They will be accessed by multiple threads concurrently, but if each thread doesn't need to wait until the other threads finish processing that class or variable, then it does not need to be thread safe. For instance, if the variable is just a counter that says how many times a method or action has been triggered, all threads can access the same variable and it wouldn't matter.

Comment: "...but if each thread doesn't need to wait until the other threads finish processing that class or variable, then it does not need to be thread safe." - That isn't true.  Thread safe means that it is safe to access the thing concurrently from multiple threads.  If you have singleton services which are not thread safe (for example, they have mutable state in them), that is a problem.

Comment: Right, but if you don't (the singleton doesn't have mutable state in them), then they don't need to be thread safe, which is what I'm talking about. If it is a stateless service, any thread can access them at any time without fear of whether or not other threads are accessing the same thing

Comment: "Right, but if you don't (the singleton doesn't have mutable state in them), then they don't need to be thread safe," - That just isn't true.  If they don't have mutable state in them they they may _be_ thread safe.  It is not the case that they don't need to be thread safe.  You definitely want your singleton beans to be thread safe.

Comment: I do see what you mean, but you are really splitting hairs.

Comment: I don't think the difference between "You definitely want your singleton beans to be thread safe"  and "... then they don't need to be thread safe" is splitting hairs.  Those are very different claims.

Comment: I know what you mean, that something is thread safe if it can be safely used in threads, regardless of if it has state or not.

Comment: Thank you @PeterLaBanca